# Explanation regarding Contao Development

Tags: xampp, content-management-system, contao

I need help regarding this issue.

I'am new to Contao, and coming from Wordpress, where the file structure (folder) is quite different, I'm having troubling of where to put the front-end files (HTML) and how to work with the Contao back-end. I'm on the way of reading the official documentation, but would really need another explanation, something like Wordpress-wise. Just so I know what files goes where and how to work around with them. Like where to put the header file, the footer file etc.
Just some explanation so I get what is goin' on and start doing it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to do. For example, there is no "header" or "footer" file. There is a general template for the front end called `fe_page`, which you can customize. But other than that, the contents of the header and footer for example can be defined in the so called *page layout* of the theme you configured.

Unfortunately the official manual is still in the process of being translated to English.

Comment: Hi @fritzmg, thanks for responding. The problem I'm having is that coming from Wordpress, you create files and you name them i.e Homepage and in the administration panel when you add a page you can select that template, while all of this is part of a theme. Let's say I want to code a filter for some products and want to have a separate page called Products and want to display that filter on that page. How can I achieve this in Contao? What file should I create? These kind of issues I can't get around Contao.
Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Contao is structured completely differently. You have a site structure, the each page in the site structure has articles and the articles are filled with so called "content elements". A content element can be a text or image for example, but also a so called "module", which you define in your theme separately. These modules can be newslists for example, or "newsreaders" to display the detail page of a news entry.

Comment: Hi @fritzmg, thanks for the explanation. I think this part I understood a bit, what I'm struggling is with the code. Let's say I created an article and added some text and need to show Articles of page Products on a page called Products that have a specific HTML structure. How to edit this structure and assign this specific HTML to a page i.e Products page.
Thanks for the help since the Contao Community, even though I registered there, I can't post and ask questions there.

Comment: Yeah, the English forum is currently broken. You could register on the German forum, we would be happy to ask any questions there. I still don't quite get your question though - I think you still expect things to work like in WordPress ;). Of what exactly do you want to edit the HTML structure? News entry detail? Page article detail?

Comment: Hi @fritzmg, thanks for still coming back to answer my questions. I think right now, I think I understood a little bit Contao. You're right, I was getting frustrated why they made some thing like they are and not like in Wordpress. I thought I would only handle the back-end side, mainly writing PHP code. But the requirements were to build the website front-end wise, meaning to write HTML, CSS and JS code, which I can't do all that, not right now, since I don't have experience on the front-end, I'm a back-end developer. And in Contao creating modules and layouts you have to deal with HTML&CSS.

Comment: So that's why after watching some videos about Contao, understood it more and saw why I was having troubling adjusting to it. I was expecting the front-end files to be given to me and I would handle the back-end part (like in Wordpress, where you have to integrate front-end files with the Wordpress code and customize Wordpress plugins and the theme with PHP code).